# The value {t cannot be converted to a number coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion

i just learning something about coldfusion.
and trying datetime with createdatetime. 
but there show error 
     **"The value {t cannot be converted to a number"**  in the line of cfset txtStartTime and cfset txtEndTime.

```
<cfset txtStartTime = createdatetime(year(txtStartDate),month(txtStartDate),day(txtStartDate),left(txtStartTime,2),right(txtStartTime,2),00)>
<cfset txtEndTime = createdatetime(year(txtEndDate),month(txtEndDate),day(txtEndDate),left(txtEndTime,2),right(txtEndTime,2),00)>
```

Am I doing something wrong? For your reference, my createdatetime value looks like this:
txtStartTime = {ts '2014-07-22 08:00:00'} and txtEndTime{ts '2014-07-22 17:00:00'}

Thank you so much guys.

Comment: From where do those two variables come?  They certainly don't look like user input.

Comment: Try using the ParseDateTime() function.  It may make this process much easier.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is your time looks like `{ts '2014-07-22 08:00:00'}`.  When you use left() or right() on that, you're treating it as a string rather than a date object.

So the 2 left-most characters would be `{t`, which isn't valid for the hours value of createDateTime, hence the error message.

Comment: thank you @duncan for your answer.
so what suppose i do to make it date object? delete the left() and the right()?

Comment: Are you actually doing `<cfset txtStartTime = "{ts '2014-07-22 08:00:00'}">` just now?  i.e. creating a STRING that looks like a date?

Comment: When you convert a date/time object to a string, it is displayed in this format `{ts '2014-07-22 08:00:00'}`. What is the source of `txtStartDate`? It may *already* date/time object? If so, there is not need for `createDateTime`. As Adam asked below, can you explain *what* you are trying to do (in plain English not code)?

Comment: Good thought duncan. That might explain it.

Comment: @duncan , i just want to make datetime object from txtstarttime to input it to database. thank you to show my mistake.
so how to change or make it correct? so the txtstarttime can be datetime object not string.

thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

It seems as if you are actually starting with something ColdFusion recognizes as a date/time, hence the `{t` issue. It also seems you want to use the hours and minutes from those initial dates/times and use `00` for the seconds. If this is the case you can simply do this:

```
<cfset txtStartTime = createdatetime(year(txtStartDate),month(txtStartDate),day(txtStartDate),hour(txtStartTime),minute(txtStartTime),00)>
<cfset txtEndTime = createdatetime(year(txtEndDate),month(txtEndDate),day(txtEndDate),hour(txtEndTime),minute(txtEndTime))>
```

Answer (score 2):

Right, so you have this:

```
left(txtStartTime,2)
right(txtStartTime,2)
```

And as you point out, the string-value of `txtStartTime` is:

```
{ts '2014-07-22 08:00:00'}
```

So what's the value of `left("{ts '2014-07-22 08:00:00'}", 2)` ? it's `{t`

What's the value of `right("{ts '2014-07-22 08:00:00'}",2)`? it's `'}`

That's now what you want, is it?

What are you actually trying to do? Not "how are you trying to solve it", but what are you trying to do?